# What is difference between reactstrap and react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I found two different bootstraps for reactjs

1. npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom
2. npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap

What is the basic and main difference between both?

Comment: Looking at github stats, `react-bootstrap` seems more active. I had some experience with `react-bootstrap` and can't say I liked it much - I still using lots of classes instead off using props on components, since they missing a lot, and documentation wasn't clear in some cases or lacked examples, BUT after checking `reactstrap` I think I will continue using `react-bootstrap` since their docs looked even worse, not sure about code though

Answer (score 41):

I have been struggling with this myself and it is as  @Besart Marku
says, highly opinion based.

One thing that did make a diffirence for me is that reactstraps documentation uses state in alot of its code examples:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class ModalExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalExample;
```

vs react-bootstrap uses functions and Hooks:

```
function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props) {
  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Modal heading
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
        <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
          dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
          consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
        </p>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
        Launch vertically centered modal
      </Button>

      <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      />
    </ButtonToolbar>
  );
}

render(<App />);
```

Im not giving an answer saying one of these is better than the other,its a preference and for me personaly I vent with reactstrap since I tend to use classcomponents more than Hooks so having finished examples that I can tweak with minimal effort did the trick.

Comment: Reactstraps now use Hooks  in their document too. Seems like they just didn't have time to rewrite those example in Hook at that time.

Comment: At the time I chose reactstrap for my project, it was because reacstrap supported nested Modals properly. React-Bootstrap didn't have a sensible way to render one modal inside another. That might be changed now.

Answer (score 31):

They are 2 different libraries but both based on Bootstrap components.

Some little statistics about them
https://www.npmtrends.com/react-bootstrap-vs-reactstrap

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But I am still confused about their usecase which one is better and why? As I can see in the link provided by you it shows its download ratio but why people select either of them?

Comment: This can't have an answer as it is a bit subjective. There are tons of material design libraries also, its just different authors. You should just read their documentation and find which is easier and prettier for you and choose

Answer (score 11):

Official documentations:

- [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)
- [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

Both work in the same way, from the perspective of use:

- They need `npm install bootstrap` to import Bootstrap stylesheet file inside index.js or App.js to enable Bootstrap default styling with `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`. ReactJS, by default, will append all Bootstrap CSS code in a style tag inside head of HTML page.

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

- Give us ready-to-use Bootstrap Components redesigned internally as JSX, without the need to use JQuery or Javascript with direct DOM manipulation (using Virtual DOM, as React already works by default);
- Behind the scenes, using `React.createElement` to render the components;

## Props

The props passed to the components can have different names depending on the package. See the Button color usage: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrapvsreactstrap-7y87c-7y87c?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Button as ReactBootstrapButton } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button as ReactstrapButton } from "reactstrap";

const App = () => (
  <>
    <ReactBootstrapButton variant="danger">React BootStrap</ReactBootstrapButton>
    <ReactstrapButton color="danger">Reactstrap</ReactstrapButton>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

The props names are different `color` and `variant`, but rendered HTML is pretty much the same, as we can see in DevTools:

[image]

## Behind the scenes

You can view both implementations, comparing a basic component as `Button` in the packages source code:

- node_modules\react-bootstrap\cjs\Button.js (React Bootstrap ^1.6.0);
- node_modules\reactstrap\dist\reactstrap.cjs.js line:930 (Reactstrap v^8.9.0);

### React Bootstrap

```js
var Button = /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.forwardRef(function (_ref, ref) {
  var bsPrefix = _ref.bsPrefix,
      variant = _ref.variant,
      size = _ref.size,
      active = _ref.active,
      className = _ref.className,
      block = _ref.block,
      type = _ref.type,
      as = _ref.as,
      props = (0, _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose2.default)(_ref, ["bsPrefix", "variant", "size", "active", "className", "block", "type", "as"]);
  var prefix = (0, _ThemeProvider.useBootstrapPrefix)(bsPrefix, 'btn');
  var classes = (0, _classnames.default)(className, prefix, active && 'active', variant && prefix + "-" + variant, block && prefix + "-block", size && prefix + "-" + size);

  if (props.href) {
    return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(_SafeAnchor.default, (0, _extends2.default)({}, props, {
      as: as,
      ref: ref,
      className: (0, _classnames.default)(classes, props.disabled && 'disabled')
    }));
  }

  if (ref) {
    props.ref = ref;
  }

  if (type) {
    props.type = type;
  } else if (!as) {
    props.type = 'button';
  }

  var Component = as || 'button';
  return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(Component, (0, _extends2.default)({}, props, {
    className: classes
  }));
});

Button.displayName = 'Button';
Button.defaultProps = defaultProps;
var _default = Button;
exports.default = _default;
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

### Reactstrap

```js
var Button = /*#__PURE__*/function (_React$Component) {
  _inheritsLoose(Button, _React$Component);

  function Button(props) {
    var _this;

    _this = _React$Component.call(this, props) || this;
    _this.onClick = _this.onClick.bind(_assertThisInitialized(_this));
    return _this;
  }

  var _proto = Button.prototype;

  _proto.onClick = function onClick(e) {
    if (this.props.disabled) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    if (this.props.onClick) {
      return this.props.onClick(e);
    }
  };

  _proto.render = function render() {
    var _this$props = this.props,
        active = _this$props.active,
        ariaLabel = _this$props['aria-label'],
        block = _this$props.block,
        className = _this$props.className,
        close = _this$props.close,
        cssModule = _this$props.cssModule,
        color = _this$props.color,
        outline = _this$props.outline,
        size = _this$props.size,
        Tag = _this$props.tag,
        innerRef = _this$props.innerRef,
        attributes = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(_this$props, ["active", "aria-label", "block", "className", "close", "cssModule", "color", "outline", "size", "tag", "innerRef"]);

    if (close && typeof attributes.children === 'undefined') {
      attributes.children = /*#__PURE__*/React__default.createElement("span", {
        "aria-hidden": true
      }, "\xD7");
    }

    var btnOutlineColor = "btn" + (outline ? '-outline' : '') + "-" + color;
    var classes = mapToCssModules(classNames(className, {
      close: close
    }, close || 'btn', close || btnOutlineColor, size ? "btn-" + size : false, block ? 'btn-block' : false, {
      active: active,
      disabled: this.props.disabled
    }), cssModule);

    if (attributes.href && Tag === 'button') {
      Tag = 'a';
    }

    var defaultAriaLabel = close ? 'Close' : null;
    return /*#__PURE__*/React__default.createElement(Tag, _extends({
      type: Tag === 'button' && attributes.onClick ? 'button' : undefined
    }, attributes, {
      className: classes,
      ref: innerRef,
      onClick: this.onClick,
      "aria-label": ariaLabel || defaultAriaLabel
    }));
  };

  return Button;
}(React__default.Component);
```

Despite some differences such as the approach with the use of prototype that `reactstrap` implements, and specifically in this component, the handling of some additional props, in general, there are no significant differences between them.

## Components List

Available components are 80% to 90% the same, and some of them just have different names.

**React Bootstrap**: Alerts, Accordion, Badge, Breadcrumb, Buttons, Button Group, Cards, Carousel, Dropdowns, Figures, Forms, Input Group, Images, Jumbotron, List Group, Modal, Navs, Navbar, Overlays, Pagination, Popovers, Progress, Spinners, Table, Tabs, Tooltips, Toasts.

**Reactstrap**: Alerts, Badge, Breadcrumbs, Button Dropdown, Button Group, Buttons, Card, Carousel, Collapse, Dropdowns, Fade, Form, Input Group, Jumbotron, Layout, List, List Group, Media, Modals, Navbar, Navs, Pagination, Popovers, Progress, Spinners, Tables, Tabs, Toasts, Tooltips.

## Benchmark

- https://www.npmtrends.com/react-bootstrap-vs-reactstrap
- https://npmcompare.com/compare/react-bootstrap,reactstrap

*You can see my full original post about it [here](https://dev.to/cassiolacerda/using-bootstrap-in-reactjs-reactstrap-or-react-bootstrap-gng)*

Answer (score 10):

Thought I'd add my 2 pence.  I came the other way, learning React Native with Android development before moving over to React.

The former method with Reactstrap is closer to how we have done things with Web Development and Bootstrap where as the latter is closer to how I have done things in React Native i.e. component based development.

Its really down to use case both make sense however if you have a dynamic page with lots of moving parts I would suggest using the React-Bootstrap library as the implementation is much closer to the component model and will allow you to make your page elements reusable (not that you can't do that with the former Reactstrap library).

I have gone with Reactstrap for now simply because it offers all of Bootstrap 4 out of the box which is what I need with very little fuss.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert of React but found an interesting comparison that might be helpful to you: https://npmcompare.com/compare/bootstrap,react-bootstrap,reactstrap

And as per the given statistics, the clear winner is react-bootstrap.

Thanks.